# Setting a common counter to different environments (figures, tables, theorems, etc)

Tags: listings, theorems, counters

I am trying to set a common counter to the environments `figure`, `table`, `algorithm`, `thm`, `lstlisting`. After searching over the internet I found a partial solution: to add the following code at the beginning of the document:

```
% sets a common counter to figures, tables and algorithms
\let\c@table\c@thm
\let\c@figure\c@thm
\let\c@algorithm\c@thm
```

However, when I add

```
\let\c@lstlisting\c@thm
```

I get an error: `Command c@lstlisting already defined.`.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: `\let` is a TeX primitive that does not check if something is already defined or not. Please post a complete minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Aside from my previous comment, note that e.g. `figure`s and `table`s are floating environments, and theorems are surely not. You are heading straight for an incomprehensible mess...

Comment: Is the \lef added BEFORE \usepackage{listings}?  If not, try \AtBeginDocument{\let...}

Comment: AFAIK the listings package defines its counter `\AtBeginDocument{...}`. Therefore the line `\let\c@lstlisting\c@thm` must be either done after `\begin{document}` or done inside `\AtBeginDocument{...}`, *after* loading the listings package. Otherwise you get the quoted error, caused by `\newcounter{lstlisting}` done by the listings package.

Comment: I actually use LyX, so I don't have full control over the code, but I can see the preview before compiling. I have already tried using '\AtBeginDocument{...}', but the it did not work. I have also tried adding the line after '\begin{document}'. Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: Ok, I might have made a type-mistake. Thanks, `\AtBeginDocuemnt{...}` worked!
@campa I just want one counter for every kind of object, so the reader doesn't need to keep track of different lists with different independent numbers in order to find something. I do agree there is a downside to this method. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: IMO the reader is more puzzled by finding figures 1 and 3 and wondering where figure 2 is...